# Android app (Kakuro helper) destined for Google Play Store advice needed

Tags: android, android-keypad, android-inputtype

I have an app that I would like to submit to Google Play Store, just to be able to say I have an app that others would find useful. I thought it would be a freebie until I found a similar app-for-pay that mine has more features than. Mine also looks better. Whatever, my questions are about the keypad.

Here are screen shots of input screens, one with output filtering. Output pops up after the `Show` button is pressed. (The `Help` button clarifies the overly-terse "output filtering" portion.)

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

The only keys I need are the ten digits 0-9 and the backspace and `Next` keys.

**Is there an input type that I haven't stumbled onto yet that would have just those 12 keys?**

**Or is there a way to hide the math symbol, `ABC`, and "Swype" keys?** (Their presence isn't overly distracting, but it would be better without them.)

(I know I could try to design my own custom keypad, but it would be really hard to set up a dozen **listeners** for a dozen new buttons and have to handle my own text field editing. Meanwhile, the existing look and feel is standard and the app is FINISHED if I don't go this route! **It wouldn't be wise to go this route would it?** A lot more work not worth the effort?)

Answer (score 1):

there is an `android:inputType="number"`, Also it wont allow any other special characters too...

Comment: @kiturk3--Thanks, but that's what I'm using. You're right of course that if any key other than 0-9, Next, and <backspace >is pressed, it is ignored--almost. If an entire field is selected and any of the math keys is pressed, the field is cleared. And Swype asks if you want to add the number to the dictionary. That's why I was wondering if I could get rid of all the unneeded keys. But as I said, if there's nothing short of a dozen listeners and field editing by hand to "cure" the problem, then i can easily live with it.